# Oracle SQL Not exists equivalent in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to write below sql equivalent query in mongodb

```
select a.id from test a
where not exists(select 1 from test b where b.id=a.id and b.name<>a.name)
```

Please advice

Comment: Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34331337/edit) link on your question to show simple documents with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $lookup syntax, example:

```
    db.collection_A.aggregate([
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "collection_B",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "references"
            }
        }, {
            "$match": {
                "references": []
            }
        }
    ])
```